# Cannot copy the file with C#

Tags: c#, io, filesystems

I am trying to make a backup module for my application, here is my code:

```
try
{
    string newDbName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Database1.accdb";
    MessageBox.Show("The current directory is: " + newDbName);
    File.Copy(backupPicker.FileName, newDbName, true);
    MessageBox.Show("Restaurare efectuata cu succes.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
} catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Nu s-a putut restaura reerva.\nMai multe informatii despre aceasta eroare pot fi gasite in jurnalul de erori.", "Eroare", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

But my application doesn't even run! Here the error message that I get from the debugger:

[image]

But actually, my application has access allowed to that location. What can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using "Database1.accdb" as resource in your application but it is read only because of TFS. Close VS, delete the file, or make it read-only false, rebuild the project. It happens soooo many times to everyone.

Here have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Comment: I fixed my error by excludin `Database1.accdb` from my Visual Studio Project.

Comment: @Victor check if i'm right and try also to clean the project and rebuild

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is what could have happened, I suspect Your application is still running behind not yet terminated. so it will be accessing the files in `StarupPath`. Or you would have opened `Database1.accdb` in some other program.

To fix this Just Delete all the binaries from `bin` and `obj` folders then restart VS. 
If that doesn't help then open `TaskManager` Kill all suspected processes related to that file.

Hope this helps