# Unable to copy file, Access to the path is denied again and again and again

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, access-denied

I kept having this annoying thing stop me from building my project over and over again even though I searched for years on stackoverflow trying to find solution but none of those I tried works. The problem just kept coming back!

The file having problem is system.web.mvc.xml, wont let me delete even I am the administrator.

Im running MVC 5 projects.

1. tried to close vs 2012 first then delete files : fine for the next build but then it came back after 1 or 2 builds
2. tried to un-check read-only option to my entire project folder : fine for the next try but , you know.
3. tried to close and re-open : same as above
4. tried to run administrator : same as above

So anyone have really get rid of this? like ever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied

Comment: I know. I read that thread over 5 times already and tried every single solution it provides below and he is using vs 2005 and Im using vs 2012 so 9 years passed since vs 2005 and something changes (and something just dont)

Comment: Restarting my machine worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same with me..
Finally I did this trick and work for me:

1. Close The Solution - Close Visual Studio. And Reopen Visual Studio and solution
2. Copy System.Web.Mvc.dll from bin folder to new fresh empty folder, I make Lib folder under solution.

[image: lib]

3. Remove read only at the dll

[image: dll read only]

4. Remove System.Web.Mvc from project reference
   [image: remove]
5. Re-add System.Web.Mvc.dll (the dll copied at Lib folder)
   [image: re-add]

__

Hope This Help

Regards