# Access to the directory path is denied

Tags: c#

I have folder stored in Debug inside the Solution Folder, but when i try to copy this folder to another one an "Access to the directory is denied" exception, can any one help?

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"Exported Files"))
{ 
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"SBooks");
    di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Directory;
    System.IO.File.Copy(@"SBooks", @"Exported Files\\");
}
```

Comment: What technology are u using? webform? mvc? wpf? winform? etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to copy file, Access to the path is denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Comment: windows form application, there is no duplication in the files

Answer (score 0):

Use **one** backslash if you are using `@` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/556133/1997232)).

```
File.Copy(@"SBooks", @"Exported Files\")
```