# MSBuild error : Unable to copy file

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a strange issue with MS Build, it fails with below error:

e:\Builds\83\ProjectName\FolderName\Sources\PROJECT\FolderName\ReleaseXX\Source\WebsiteName.metaproj: Unable to copy file "e:\Builds\83\ProjectName\FolderName\Binaries\Some.dll" to "WebsiteName\Bin\Some.dll". Access to the path 'WebsiteName\Bin\Some.dll' is denied.

The path Access to path is invalid, i really not able to figure out from where that path is being referred to. Do any one have any guidance on this

Comment: Are you running the build  in local VS or through TFS? And for TFS which build are you running XAML or vNext?

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple solutions in this similar question: [Unable to copy file, Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied) You could give a try with it.

Besides if you are running TFS build, to narrow down the issue, suggest you use your build service account to manually run the build on the build agent. This will narrow down if  the issue related to TFS build definition or not. Also make sure your build service account have enough permission and the folder of path is not read only.