# Monodevelop won't Run any project

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop, godot

**Hey,**
I was using Monodevelop for some time(~4 months) and everything was perfect until this week.

Now whenever I try to Run a console project I get this error: `/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj/x86/Release/AppName.exe" to "bin/Release/AppName.exe". Access to the path is denied. (MSB3021) (AppName)`.
The strange thing is that when I go to the folder `bin/Release` I DO find the AppName.exe. so I used manually `mono AppName.exe` to run the app.

An other problem is that in Godot mono I have the same error :`/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4215,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file ".mono/temp/obj/Tools/GodotTestAA.dll" to ".mono/temp/bin/Tools/GodotTestAA.dll". Access to the path is denied.` when I try to run a scene, so I can't even try my game.

I thought that the problem is from my installation of mono or monodevelop so I completely purged both of them and reinstalled them again, but nothing.

I also tried to run Godot mono as root(as root not with administrative rights), it worked but I know that it isn't good to run apps as root so I decided to look for another solution in the monodevelop forums, godot forums and here, but the only thing that I found is: [Unable to copy file, Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied) but the post was 8 years old and any of the solution worked

> Note: I am on Ubuntu(PopOS exactly).

*I will really appreciate your help ;)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I did some more research and tests I found that the problem is from my drive file format, mono(for some reasons) is not compatible with exfat file format.

So to fix the problem you will have to move your project to an ext drive.