# Unable to copy file access to the path is denied

Tags: file, directory, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to copy a database file `mdf` from folder `DATA` that exist under `Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL`

but I'm getting this exception :

```
Unable to copy file  `\..\database.mdf` to the path is denied
```

I know that my question is duplicate, but I have tried all solutions posted in this question but any of them worked for me.

[Unable to copy file - access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

I think that Windows 10 is thinking more than usual about folders security.

I'm trying also to remove the read-only attribute from a folder, it removes for the first time but when I open the property of the folder in the second I found that the attribute read-only is checked again

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem after running the VS 2019 as admin.