# Unable to copy file 'source' to 'destination' while building application in visual studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

I am working on Web API Project in ASP.NET Core using .NET 6.0. I have also added some features of MVC to view the data. Everything was working fine. Suddenly, while modifying the project, i have tried to build the application, i have received error

> Unable to copy file
> "D:\Soliton\Applications\MachineManagement\ServerAPI\MMAPIApp\MMAPIApp\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe"
> to "bin\Debug\net6.0\MMAPIApp.exe". Access to the path
> 'bin\Debug\net6.0\MMAPIApp.exe' is denied.

[image]

I have tried to give rights to everyone to the source and destination folders.

Answer (score 0):

The path `'bin\Debug\net6.0\MMAPIApp.exe'` is an *executable* file, and not a *directory*.  Whatever you modified, you probably inputted the incorrect path.  You probably meant `bin\Debug\net6.0` as this would be a valid directory path to copy a file to.

Comment: Hi @Timothy I am doing nothing against this .exe file. I have modified HTML in view and tried to build the project. It gave me this error. Can you please further help me on it? How to get rid of this?

Comment: Perhaps the app is running / some process has a handle on the executable?

Comment: @AkhtarAbbas perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130136/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied